# Reference Needed: Time Dilation for Muons Reaching Earth's Surface

Tags: special-relativity, specific-reference

On the Hyperphysics Site we have the following page:

[Hyperphysics, "Muon Experiment", http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/muon.html](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/muon.html)

which makes the following statement as its first line:

> "The measurement of the flux of muons at the Earth's surface produced an early dilemma because many more are detected than would be expected, based on their short half-life of 1.56 microseconds."

Can anyone give me a reference for the discussion of this "early dilemma". It implies to me that the unexpectedly high muon flux was discussed as an anomaly before the [1941 Rossi-Hall experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation_of_moving_particles#Rossi.E2.80.93Hall_experiment).

Can anyone give me a reference to such earlier works, or was Rossi-Hall the first to address this issue?

Comment: confusion on values comes from : half-life of 1.56 μs and mean lifetime of 2.2 μs

Comment: in 1940 , Rossi and Hal thought first they were observing mesons instead of muons , both discovered in 1936. It seems that there was no other time dilatation of cosmic particles experiment between 1936 and 1940.

Comment: @igael Yes of course: I was mixing mean and halflives. I don't often think in terms of halflives so I think I was reading the two to be the same. Duh!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate on the [History of Science SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have to disagree with you @John. Questions can be on-topic on more than one site, and this seems tailor made for our [specific-reference] tag. Now, I *am* willing to migrate it if Rod wants as it looks to be a very good match for [hsm.se].

Comment: The Hyperphysics site is wrong. The lifetime was first measured from measurements of the atmospheric muon flux through various absorbers, and Rossi and Hall were well aware that SR had to be taken into account when analysing the results. So they used their knowledge of time dilation to calculate the lifetime. Claims that *more muons were observed than expected* are simply untrue.